# Is there a way to turn off reflection on a method?

Tags: java, servlets, reflection, xml-rpc

Using XML-RPC client and server, redstone.xmlrpc.XmlRpcServlet and XmlRpcClient

I don't have control of the implementation of the Servlet, but just the client. I am sending an object to the servlet.

The servlet seems to be using some form of reflection on the object I send it.  The problem is that I have a method on the object called:

```
 public boolean isPhysicalDevice()
 {
    return !getAddress().isChannel();
 }
```

However, the servlet gets a list of the keys on the object and gets one key as "physicalDevice", which is not an attribute of the object but only exists as part of the name of this method.  Is there a way, I can perhaps annotate the method on the object I send, so the servlet doesn't try to reflect this method and treat it as an attribute of the object?

Comment: AFAIK you should change a transfer object with plain getters and setters of the necessary attributes. But I hope there could be a better approach.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a [`BeanInfo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/beans/BeanInfo.html) for the class, to clarify that the method is not an attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the interface you want the servlet to see and pass it a Proxy for that interface which simply delegates every invocation to your object. (Proxy is Serializable.)